# Chrome remembering manual accepted SSL certificates

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have implemented a testsite and secured it with https. As the certificate is not valid, Chrome and Firefox enforce me to manually accept the ssl certificate.

If I accept it in Firefox, I can see this setting in `~/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db`. For Chrome however, I can not find any preference setting in

- `/etc/opt/chrome`
- `~/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db`
- `~/.pki/nssdb/key4.db`
- `/.config/google-chrome/Default/Web Data` or any other file from this folder.

Yet Chrome somehow remember this setting even after a reboot.

On which location on the disk is this preference stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm, I figured it out, in case anyone is looking for it:

Chrome does not store this setting in a db. Its stored in its `Preferences` file (`~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences`)
Inside, its stored at the json-path `["profile"]["content_settings"]["exceptions"]["ssl_cert_decisions"]`